# storing integer values in a bool variable

Tags: c++, string, int, boolean

I'm trying to store integer values in a boolean array, however when I print the values out, they only come out as 1's and 0's which I assume represent true and false. Is there any way to store values greater than 1 or less than 0 in a bool? Thanks in advance for the help! :D

Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    bool set[2];

    set[0] = 7;
    set[1] = 13;

    string setNotation = "{"+to_string(set[0])+", "+to_string(set[1])+"}";

    cout << setNotation << endl; //prints out as {1, 1} instead of {7, 13}

    //note: I have to use to_string to append and not cout << "{" << set[0] << ...
    //because I'm using this in a method that returns a string

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this a serious question?

Comment: Why would you need to store integer values in a boolean array, anyway?

Comment: hey guys, not my idea... its for a class project. If I had it my way I'd use vectors lol

Answer (score 1):

Nope, bools are designed to only store a 1 or a 0. Sorry about that. You might want to try an int.

Answer (score 1):

Bool data type is internally implemented as an integer in C++, but the only allowed values for bool data type are 1's and 0's. So you can't store any other value except 1's and 0's in a variable of type bool.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use bool array and read it like a binary if that's what you are trying to do. 
So for example integer 7 is represented by 3-element array:

```
arr[0]=1
arr[1]=1
arr[2]=1
```

and now you have 111 (binary) = 7

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using raw pointers, i.e. `*(unsigned char *)&set[0] = 7;`.

However, it is not a good idea and these situations (other-than-0-or-1 value stored in bool) usually happen only due to a bug in the code (use of an uninitialized memory etc.). Behavior of the variable is undefined and can be quite surprising, e.g. `!set[0]` evaluates to `6` in your program (i.e. both `set[0]` ans `!set[0]` behave as `true` in conditions) but when printed in gdb, `!set[0]` evaluates to `false`, which can be really confusing when debugging complicated programs...

In two words: not suggested